# Regular Expressions find shortest match?

Tags: java, regex

My program retrieves an HTML page contents and then looks for jpg images links in the page.

I want to use regular expressions to catch the images however I fot a problem here..

In order to do that I used the pattern

> "http.*?jpg"

but that brings me to catch expressions like:
"http://someURL...http://imageURL.jpg"

so I guess what i want to find is the shortest match, i.e. find "jpg" and look backwards to the first "http"

***Is it possible using regex?***

Comment: Just take the whole match then do some string manipulation to go backward to the last `/`

Comment: What does this "http://someURL...http://imageURL.jpg" mean? It does not look like legal URL. Could you post the full URL that matched by your regex?

Comment: yes. like this:http:\/\/bs.serving-sys.com\/BurstingPipe\/adServer.bs?cn=tf&c=20&mc=click&pli=4617738&PluID=0&ord=%CACHEBUSTER%","statUrl":"http:\/\/bs.serving-sys.com\/BurstingPipe\/adServer.bs?cn=tf&c=19&mc=imp&pli=4617738&PluID=0&ord=%CACHEBUSTER%&rtu=-1"}],"headline":[{"src":"\/images\/pause_bituah_iashir_254x143.jpg

Comment: A cleaner option to a single regex is to come up with a single good regex which can extract each full `http://...` URL regardless of whether it is a `.jpg`, and then filter the list down afterwards (be it with another regex or simply `url.endsWith(".jpg")`).

Comment: We dont get to the bottom of it. is there a general pattern that allows us to efficiently catch the shortest match?

Answer (score 3):

try `http:[^:]*?jpg` which is a hacky way to make sure you only have one semicolon, and therefore only one http: block, you can further select out common delimiters for urls

`http:[^:\"\}\{\s]*?\.jpg`

Comment: Ah - won't that not get ANY links then? I think you need `http:[^:]*?jpg` or similar...

Comment: Needs some tweaking as josh mentions, but this is a straightforward way of doing it.  And it's not that hacky either.  You have to say to yourself, "how can **I** tell that `http://aaa http://imageurl.jpg` is not what I want?" And the answer could be "well, it has two `http://`s in it", or "it has a space in it", etc.  Then you need to train the regex to do the same, whether that's by disallowing spaces, or an entire internal `http://`.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a negative lookahead based regex to make sure shortest text is matched between `http://` and .jpg` like this:

```
/http:\/\/(?!.*?http:\/\/).+?\.jpe?g/
```